# How to read timezone datetime objects

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have a timezone aware datetime object, which, if printed contains: `2013-03-04 18:00:00+01:00`. But I always fail to understand how to read them. Does this refers to 19:00 local time or to 18:00 local time?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC might be useful.

Comment: Yeah I have the same question in the SQL world.
That wiki article helps somewhat... but its still not very clear.

These timezone things are doing my head in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means 18:00 local time, in a place which is +1 hour from UTC (so Western Europe, for example).

Comment: Ok. That's strange. I wonder why Django saves it one hour wrong when using USE_TZ, but that's another question...

Comment: @NiclasNilsson it saves it as utc thats why you are getting the one hour shift. If you are having other problems with timezone and datetimes check out http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @myusuf3 Yeah. It all makes sense to me now (I believe). Thanks alot!